# Class number does not exist

Tags: admin, magento2.4.2

**Hello everyone!**
When using the action "Update attributes"[image]

I get an error: [image]

The error started showing up after updating magento version to 2.4.2
Have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you try to remove generated folder and then run the commands again and check.

Comment: yes,i tried but it didn't work for me

Comment: Did you get to solve it? I also have this issue but with an API endpoint.

Comment: magento has no standard render for type number